# Magento frontend call controller index action redirect to home page

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I'm try to access the index action of frontend index controller but it redirect to home page.

When I'm try to access index action it redirect to home page.

My extension code in community.

**Note: The code is working fine on local on windows OS But when these code is upload on linux server it's not working**

Below is my Code & files path:

IndexController.php

```
Path:`app/code/community/Magentostudy/News/controllers/IndexController.php` 
<?php
 /**
 * News frontend controller
 *
 * @author Magento
 */
class Magentostudy_News_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /**
     * Pre dispatch action that allows to redirect to no route page in case of disabled extension through admin panel
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->isEnabled()) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            $this->_redirect('noRoute');
        }        
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    { die('kailas');
        $this->loadLayout();

        $listBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('news.list');

        if ($listBlock) {
            $currentPage = abs(intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')));
            if ($currentPage < 1) {
                $currentPage = 1;
            }
            $listBlock->setCurrentPage($currentPage);
        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * News view action
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $newsId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if (!$newsId) {
            return $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }

        /** @var $model Magentostudy_News_Model_News */
        $model = Mage::getModel('magentostudy_news/news');
        $model->load($newsId);

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            return $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }

        Mage::register('news_item', $model);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('before_news_item_display', array('news_item' => $model));

        $this->loadLayout();
        $itemBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('news.item');
        if ($itemBlock) {
            $listBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('news.list');
            if ($listBlock) {
                $page = (int)$listBlock->getCurrentPage() ? (int)$listBlock->getCurrentPage() : 1;
            } else {
                $page = 1;
            }
            $itemBlock->setPage($page);
        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Config.xml

```
Path: app/code/community/Magentostudy/News/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Module configuration
 *
 * @author Magento
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentostudy_News>
            <version>1.0.0.0.1</version>
        </Magentostudy_News>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <magentostudy_news>
                <class>Magentostudy_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
            </magentostudy_news>
            <news_resource>
                <class>Magentostudy_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <news>
                        <table>magentostudy_news</table>
                    </news>
                </entities>
            </news_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <magentostudy_news>
                <class>Magentostudy_News_Helper</class>
            </magentostudy_news>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <magentostudy_news>
                <class>Magentostudy_News_Block</class>
            </magentostudy_news>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <magentostudy_news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Magentostudy_News</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </magentostudy_news_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <before_news_item_display>
                <observers>
                    <magentostudy_news>
                        <class>magentostudy_news/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeNewsDisplayed</method>
                    </magentostudy_news>
                </observers>
            </before_news_item_display>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <magentostudy_news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentostudy_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </magentostudy_news>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <magentostudy_news>
                    <file>magentostudy_news.xml</file>
                </magentostudy_news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Magentostudy_News before="Mage_Adminhtml">Magentostudy_News_Adminhtml</Magentostudy_News>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <magentostudy_news>
                    <file>magentostudy_news.xml</file>
                </magentostudy_news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <news>
            <view>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <items_per_page>20</items_per_page>
                <days_difference>3</days_difference>
            </view>
        </news>
    </default>
</config>
```

magentostudy_news.xml (Layout XML)

```
Path: app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/magentostudy_news.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento frontend layout
 *
 * @author Magento
 */
-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="magentostudy_news" ifconfig="news/view/enabled">
                <label>News</label>
                <url>news</url>
                <title>News</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <magentostudy_news_index_index translate="label">
        <label>News Page</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="magentostudy_news">
                <title>Site News</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="magentostudy_news/list" name="news.list" template="magentostudy/news/list.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="news.list.pager" as="news_list_pager" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </magentostudy_news_index_index>

    <magentostudy_news_index_view translate="label">
        <label>News Item Page</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="magentostudy_news/item" name="news.item" template="magentostudy/news/item.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </magentostudy_news_index_view>
</layout>
```

Magentostudy_News.xml (enable module)

```
Path: app/etc/modules/Magentostudy_News.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Module initial config
 *
 * @author Magento
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentostudy_News>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Magentostudy_News>
    </modules>
</config>
```

list.phtml (template phtml file)

```
Path:app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magentostudy/news/list.phtml
<?php
/**
 * News template for items list
 *
 * @author Magento
 */

/**
 * @var $this Magentostudy_News_Block_List
 * @see Magentostudy_News_Block_List
 */
?>
<div id="news_list_messages"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Site News') ?></h1>
</div>

<div class="news_list_view">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCollection() as $newsItem): ?>
        <div id="item_<?php echo $newsItem->getId() ?>" class="news_list_item">
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getItemUrl($newsItem) ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($newsItem->getTitle()) ?>
                </a>
            </h2>

            <div class="news_item_subtitle">
                <?php echo $this->formatDate($newsItem->getTimePublished(), 'medium') ?> |
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($newsItem->getAuthor()) ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ($imageUrl = $this->getImageUrl($newsItem, 100)): ?>
               <p><img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($newsItem->getTitle()); ?>" /></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php echo $this->getPager() ?>
```

Comment: can you tell me please put the code for the frontend?

Comment: I've update the question with frontend template phtml file. please have look.

Comment: please type your domain.com/index.php/news in your Url and check

Comment: I've tried already & check once again as you said but it's not working. is their any case sensitive issues.

Comment: I added die in IndexController it show the message in die. but not goes in  IndexController class action even class constructor. What's wrong in my controller.

Comment: I cant found where is call you indexAction contrller form phtml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38416/discussion-between-kailas-and-ajay-patel).

Comment: constructor is called ? 

class Magentostudy_News_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /**
     * Pre dispatch action that allows to redirect to no route page in case of disabled extension through admin panel
     */
 function __construct() {
  
       die("testing");
    
   }

Answer (score 1):

There may be permission issue with your file in linux server. Please add appropriate permission and try once.

Comment: current permission is 755

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not defined namespace **IndexController.php** , at least in your code above also i would like to point out that in linux the file paths are **case-sensitive** while in windows its not , so it is maybe a path related issue.